# Компиляция из ___.jade с помощью Koala в ____.html .......?

Tags: jade

При компиляции из ___.jade  с помощью Koala в ____.html, код не переносится  на следующую строку в ____.html, т.е. не выстраивается дерево документа из кода.
Все элементы и строчные и блочные отображаются в одну строку, что становится весьма не удобочитаемым.
Есть якобы способ устранения данной проблемы через внесения в командную строку node.js команды "-P", но я не могу связать это с работой Koala.

Что конкретно нужно сделать, что бы код компилировался корректно.

Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Поставьте в настройках Jade в Koala галочку возле "Format HTML With Whitespace". Этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?